# What is the purpose of meshgrid in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mesh, numpy-ndarray

What is the purpose of [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)? I know it creates some kind of grid of coordinates for plotting, but I can't see the direct benefit of it.

The official documentation gives the following example, but its output doesn't make sense to me:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Note that if `x = np.arange(n)` and `y = np.arange(m)`, you can use `np.indices((m, n))` directly instead of `np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="ij"))`.

Answer (score 625, accepted):

The purpose of `meshgrid` is to create a rectangular grid out of an array of x values and an array of y values.

So, for example, if we want to create a grid where we have a point at each integer value between 0 and 4 in both the x and y directions. To create a rectangular grid, we need every combination of the `x` and `y` points.

This is going to be 25 points, right? So if we wanted to create an x and y array for all of these points, we *could* do the following.

```
x[0,0] = 0    y[0,0] = 0
x[0,1] = 1    y[0,1] = 0
x[0,2] = 2    y[0,2] = 0
x[0,3] = 3    y[0,3] = 0
x[0,4] = 4    y[0,4] = 0
x[1,0] = 0    y[1,0] = 1
x[1,1] = 1    y[1,1] = 1
...
x[4,3] = 3    y[4,3] = 4
x[4,4] = 4    y[4,4] = 4
```

This would result in the following `x` and `y` matrices, such that the pairing of the corresponding element in each matrix gives the x and y coordinates of a point in the grid.

```
x =   0 1 2 3 4        y =   0 0 0 0 0
      0 1 2 3 4              1 1 1 1 1
      0 1 2 3 4              2 2 2 2 2
      0 1 2 3 4              3 3 3 3 3
      0 1 2 3 4              4 4 4 4 4
```

We can then plot these to verify that they are a grid:

```
plt.plot(x,y, marker='.', color='k', linestyle='none')
```

[image]

Obviously, this gets very tedious especially for large ranges of `x` and `y`. Instead, `meshgrid` can actually generate this for us: all we have to specify are the unique `x` and `y` values.

```
xvalues = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
yvalues = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Now, when we call `meshgrid`, we get the previous output automatically.

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xvalues, yvalues)

plt.plot(xx, yy, marker='.', color='k', linestyle='none')
```

[image]

Creation of these rectangular grids is useful for a number of tasks. In the example that you have provided in your post, it is simply a way to sample a function (`sin(x**2 + y**2) / (x**2 + y**2)`) over a range of values for `x` and `y`.

Because this function has been sampled on a rectangular grid, the function can now be visualized as an "image".

[image]

Additionally, the result can now be passed to functions which expect data on rectangular grid (i.e. `contourf`)

Comment: You haven't explained the return values `xx` and `yy`. The mysterious part for me was why it returns that pair of results, and what they look like.  Hai Phan's answer is handy for that.  I guess it does that for convenience, since plot wants two parameters like that.

Comment: I don't know - that's why I'm looking this information up ;)  So I'm not saying it should return something different. I'm just providing my best guess at a missing piece of information for those who just read the accepted answer.  And if you like, I'm suggesting that your answer (which is already very nice - thank you!) would be a bit more complete if you explained the return values (as Hai did), for those of us that are still puzzled.

Comment: To better understand the values of xx and yy, consider the claim that the following code gets you the same result as np.meshgrid: `xx = [xvalues for y in yvalues]`
`yy = [[y for x in xvalues] for y in yvalues]`

Comment: @problemofficer May be this will help: https://youtu.be/r6OD07Qq2mw?t=2250

Comment: @nealmcb the `xx` and `yy` values returned is that pair of matrices shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-numpy#:~:text=point%20in%20the-,grid,-.)

Answer (score 393):

Courtesy of Microsoft Excel:

[image]

Comment: Nice. Fwiw, if you want a 2 x 12 array of the pairs in the middle: `XYpairs = np.vstack([ XX.reshape(-1), YY.reshape(-1) ])`

Comment: and if you want a 12 x 2 array of the pairs in the middle: `XYpairs = np.dstack([XX, YY]).reshape(-1, 2)`

Comment: Nice answer. The purpose of meshgrid is to create a grid by using the coordinate of each dim.

Comment: What I find a little strange is that the x and y values are returned separately instead of already combined into one array. If I want them in one array, I need to do: `np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T`

Answer (score 157):

Actually the purpose of `np.meshgrid` is already mentioned in the documentation:

> [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)
>
> Return coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors.
>
> Make N-D coordinate arrays for vectorized evaluations of N-D scalar/vector fields over N-D grids, given one-dimensional coordinate arrays x1, x2,..., xn.

So it's primary purpose is to create a coordinates matrices.

You probably just asked yourself:

#### Why do we need to create coordinate matrices?

The reason you need coordinate matrices with Python/NumPy is that there is no direct relation from coordinates to values, except when your coordinates start with zero and are purely positive integers. Then you can just use the indices of an array as the index.
However when that's not the case you somehow need to store coordinates alongside your data. That's where grids come in.

Suppose your data is:

```
1  2  1
2  5  2
1  2  1
```

However, each value represents a 3 x 2 kilometer area (horizontal x vertical). Suppose your origin is the upper left corner and you want arrays that represent the distance you could use:

```
import numpy as np
h, v = np.meshgrid(np.arange(3)*3, np.arange(3)*2)
```

where v is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

and h:

```
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [0, 3, 6],
       [0, 3, 6]])
```

So if you have two indices, let's say `x` and `y` (that's why the return value of `meshgrid` is usually `xx` or `xs` instead of `x` in this case I chose `h` for horizontally!) then you can get the x coordinate of the point, the y coordinate of the point and the value at that point by using:

```
h[x, y]    # horizontal coordinate
v[x, y]    # vertical coordinate
data[x, y]  # value
```

That makes it much easier to keep track of coordinates **and** (even more importantly) you can pass them to functions that need to know the coordinates.

### A slightly longer explanation

However, `np.meshgrid` itself isn't often used directly, mostly one just uses one of *similar* objects `np.mgrid` or `np.ogrid`.
Here `np.mgrid` represents the `sparse=False` and `np.ogrid` the `sparse=True` case (I refer to the `sparse` argument of `np.meshgrid`). Note that there is a significant difference between
`np.meshgrid` and `np.ogrid` and `np.mgrid`: The first two returned values (if there are two or more) are reversed. Often this doesn't matter but you should give meaningful variable names depending on the context.

For example, in case of a 2D grid and `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` it makes sense to name the first returned item of `np.meshgrid` `x` and the second one `y` while it's
the other way around for `np.mgrid` and `np.ogrid`.

#### [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html#numpy.ogrid) and sparse grids

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> yy, xx = np.ogrid[-5:6, -5:6]
>>> xx
array([[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
>>> yy
array([[-5],
       [-4],
       [-3],
       [-2],
       [-1],
       [ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5]])
```

As already said the output is reversed when compared to `np.meshgrid`, that's why I unpacked it as `yy, xx` instead of `xx, yy`:

```
>>> xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5, 6), np.arange(-5, 6), sparse=True)
>>> xx
array([[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
>>> yy
array([[-5],
       [-4],
       [-3],
       [-2],
       [-1],
       [ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5]])
```

This already looks like coordinates, specifically the x and y lines for 2D plots.

Visualized:

```
yy, xx = np.ogrid[-5:6, -5:6]
plt.figure()
plt.title('ogrid (sparse meshgrid)')
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(xx.ravel())
plt.yticks(yy.ravel())
plt.scatter(xx, np.zeros_like(xx), color="blue", marker="*")
plt.scatter(np.zeros_like(yy), yy, color="red", marker="x")
```

[image]

#### [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) and dense/fleshed out grids

```
>>> yy, xx = np.mgrid[-5:6, -5:6]
>>> xx
array([[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
>>> yy
array([[-5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5],
       [-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4],
       [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5]])
```

The same applies here: The output is reversed compared to `np.meshgrid`:

```
>>> xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-5, 6), np.arange(-5, 6))
>>> xx
array([[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
>>> yy
array([[-5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5],
       [-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4],
       [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5]])
```

Unlike `ogrid` these arrays contain **all** `xx` and `yy` coordinates in the -5 <= xx <= 5; -5 <= yy <= 5 grid.

```
yy, xx = np.mgrid[-5:6, -5:6]
plt.figure()
plt.title('mgrid (dense meshgrid)')
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(xx[0])
plt.yticks(yy[:, 0])
plt.scatter(xx, yy, color="red", marker="x")
```

[image]

#### Functionality

It's not only limited to 2D, these functions work for arbitrary dimensions (well, there is a maximum number of arguments given to function in Python and a maximum number of dimensions that NumPy allows):

```
>>> x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.ogrid[:3, 1:4, 2:5, 3:6]
>>> for i, x in enumerate([x1, x2, x3, x4]):
...     print('x{}'.format(i+1))
...     print(repr(x))
x1
array([[[[0]]],


       [[[1]]],


       [[[2]]]])
x2
array([[[[1]],

        [[2]],

        [[3]]]])
x3
array([[[[2],
         [3],
         [4]]]])
x4
array([[[[3, 4, 5]]]])

>>> # equivalent meshgrid output, note how the first two arguments are reversed and the unpacking
>>> x2, x1, x3, x4 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,4), np.arange(3), np.arange(2, 5), np.arange(3, 6), sparse=True)
>>> for i, x in enumerate([x1, x2, x3, x4]):
...     print('x{}'.format(i+1))
...     print(repr(x))
# Identical output so it's omitted here.
```

Even if these also work for 1D there are two (much more common) 1D grid creation functions:

- [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)
- [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Besides the `start` and `stop` argument it also supports the `step` argument (even complex steps that represent the number of steps):

```
>>> x1, x2 = np.mgrid[1:10:2, 1:10:4j]
>>> x1  # The dimension with the explicit step width of 2
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [7., 7., 7., 7.],
       [9., 9., 9., 9.]])
>>> x2  # The dimension with the "number of steps"
array([[ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.],
       [ 1.,  4.,  7., 10.]])
```

### Applications

You specifically asked about the purpose and in fact, these grids are extremely useful if you need a coordinate system.

For example if you have a NumPy function that calculates the distance in two dimensions:

```
def distance_2d(x_point, y_point, x, y):
    return np.hypot(x-x_point, y-y_point)
```

And you want to know the distance of each point:

```
>>> ys, xs = np.ogrid[-5:5, -5:5]
>>> distances = distance_2d(1, 2, xs, ys)  # distance to point (1, 2)
>>> distances
array([[9.21954446, 8.60232527, 8.06225775, 7.61577311, 7.28010989,
        7.07106781, 7.        , 7.07106781, 7.28010989, 7.61577311],
       [8.48528137, 7.81024968, 7.21110255, 6.70820393, 6.32455532,
        6.08276253, 6.        , 6.08276253, 6.32455532, 6.70820393],
       [7.81024968, 7.07106781, 6.40312424, 5.83095189, 5.38516481,
        5.09901951, 5.        , 5.09901951, 5.38516481, 5.83095189],
       [7.21110255, 6.40312424, 5.65685425, 5.        , 4.47213595,
        4.12310563, 4.        , 4.12310563, 4.47213595, 5.        ],
       [6.70820393, 5.83095189, 5.        , 4.24264069, 3.60555128,
        3.16227766, 3.        , 3.16227766, 3.60555128, 4.24264069],
       [6.32455532, 5.38516481, 4.47213595, 3.60555128, 2.82842712,
        2.23606798, 2.        , 2.23606798, 2.82842712, 3.60555128],
       [6.08276253, 5.09901951, 4.12310563, 3.16227766, 2.23606798,
        1.41421356, 1.        , 1.41421356, 2.23606798, 3.16227766],
       [6.        , 5.        , 4.        , 3.        , 2.        ,
        1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 2.        , 3.        ],
       [6.08276253, 5.09901951, 4.12310563, 3.16227766, 2.23606798,
        1.41421356, 1.        , 1.41421356, 2.23606798, 3.16227766],
       [6.32455532, 5.38516481, 4.47213595, 3.60555128, 2.82842712,
        2.23606798, 2.        , 2.23606798, 2.82842712, 3.60555128]])
```

The output would be identical if one passed in a dense grid instead of an open grid. NumPys broadcasting makes it possible!

Let's visualize the result:

```
plt.figure()
plt.title('distance to point (1, 2)')
plt.imshow(distances, origin='lower', interpolation="none")
plt.xticks(np.arange(xs.shape[1]), xs.ravel())  # need to set the ticks manually
plt.yticks(np.arange(ys.shape[0]), ys.ravel())
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

And this is also when NumPys `mgrid` and `ogrid` become very convenient because it allows you to easily change the resolution of your grids:

```
ys, xs = np.ogrid[-5:5:200j, -5:5:200j]
# otherwise same code as above
```

[image]

However, since `imshow` doesn't support `x` and `y` inputs one has to change the ticks by hand. It would be really convenient if it would accept the `x` and `y` coordinates, right?

It's easy to write functions with NumPy that deal naturally with grids.  Furthermore, there are several functions in NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib that expect you to pass in the grid.

I like images so let's explore [`matplotlib.pyplot.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html):

```
ys, xs = np.mgrid[-5:5:200j, -5:5:200j]
density = np.sin(ys)-np.cos(xs)
plt.figure()
plt.contour(xs, ys, density)
```

[image]

Note how the coordinates are already correctly set! That wouldn't be the case if you just passed in the `density`.

Or to give another fun example using [astropy models](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/) (this time I don't care much about the coordinates, I just use them to create *some* grid):

```
from astropy.modeling import models
z = np.zeros((100, 100))
y, x = np.mgrid[0:100, 0:100]
for _ in range(10):
    g2d = models.Gaussian2D(amplitude=100, 
                           x_mean=np.random.randint(0, 100), 
                           y_mean=np.random.randint(0, 100), 
                           x_stddev=3, 
                           y_stddev=3)
    z += g2d(x, y)
    a2d = models.AiryDisk2D(amplitude=70, 
                            x_0=np.random.randint(0, 100), 
                            y_0=np.random.randint(0, 100), 
                            radius=5)
    z += a2d(x, y)
```

[image]

Although that's just "for the looks" several functions related to functional models and fitting (for example [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d),
[`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) even show examples using `np.mgrid`) in Scipy, etc. require grids. Most of these work with open grids and dense grids, however some only work with one of them.

Comment: `meshgrid` prime purpose is not to create grid coordinates, but to [replace slow Python for-loops by vector operations taking place in the C library NumPy](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/). Arrays should be used for X-Y coordinates, so that all Z values can be computed **at once** by vector operations on X and Y arrays. A way to obtain these shape-compatible X-Y arrays is to use `meshgrid`.

Answer (score 49):

Suppose you have a function:

```
def sinus2d(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.sin(y)
```

and you want, for example, to see what it looks like in the range 0 to 2*pi. How would you do it? There `np.meshgrid` comes in:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100), np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))
z = sinus2d(xx, yy) # Create the image on this grid
```

and such a plot would look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(z, origin='lower', interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So `np.meshgrid` is just a convenience. In principle the same could be done by:

```
z2 = sinus2d(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)[:,None], np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)[None,:])
```

but there you need to be aware of your dimensions (suppose you have more than two ...) and the right broadcasting. `np.meshgrid` does all of this for you.

Also meshgrid allows you to delete coordinates together with the data if you, for example, want to do an interpolation but exclude certain values:

```
condition = z>0.6
z_new = z[condition] # This will make your array 1D
```

so how would you do the interpolation now? You can give `x` and `y` to an interpolation function like `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` so you need a way to know which coordinates were deleted:

```
x_new = xx[condition]
y_new = yy[condition]
```

and then you can still interpolate with the "right" coordinates (try it without the meshgrid and you will have a lot of extra code):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
interpolated = interp2d(x_new, y_new, z_new)
```

and the original meshgrid allows you to get the interpolation on the original grid again:

```
interpolated_grid = interpolated(xx[0], yy[:, 0]).reshape(xx.shape)
```

These are just some examples where I used the `meshgrid` there might be a lot more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The most confusing moment for me is returned values `xx`, `yy`. It was difficult to understand what they are and  why we use them to calculate the function. Seems, I got it. We want to calculate some function based on coordinates. We can write something like this:
`for x=1:10:
  for y=1:10:
    z[x,y]=sin(x)+sin(y)`
Instead we calculate `z` in a different way `z=sin([x,x,...,x]) + sin([y,y,..y])`. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Actually you always need the double loop (your first code). But there are different ways to archieve it with `numpy`: meshgrid or broadcasting. If you don't discard points (see last part of my answer) both are actually functionally equivalent. Broadcasting is just an implicit loop across the to-be-broadcasted dimension. Note that I used `[:,None]` and `[None, :]` to include extra dimensions so the result broadcasts correctly. Your second example is more like: `sin([[y],[y],..[y]])`

Answer (score 21):

**Short answer**

The purpose of `meshgrid` is to help [replace slow Python loops](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/) by faster vectorized operations available in NumPy library. `meshgrid` role is to prepare 2D arrays required by the vectorized operation.

**Basic example showing the principle**

Let's say we have two sequences of values,

```
a = [2,7,9,20]    
b = [1,6,7,9]    ​
```

and we want to perform an operation on each possible pair of values, one taken from the first list, one taken from the second list. We also want to store the result. For example, let's say we want to get the sum of the values for each possible pair.

*Slow and laborious method*

```
c = []    
for i in range(len(b)):    
    row = []    
    for j in range(len(a)):    
        row.append (a[j] + b[i])
    c.append (row)    
print (c)
```

Result:

```
[[3, 8, 10, 21],
 [8, 13, 15, 26],
 [9, 14, 16, 27],
 [11, 16, 18, 29]]
```

*Fast and easy method*

```
i,j = np.meshgrid (a,b)    
c = i + j    
print (c)
```

Result:

```
[[ 3  8 10 21]
 [ 8 13 15 26]
 [ 9 14 16 27]
 [11 16 18 29]]
```

You can see from this basic illustration how the explicit slow Python loops have been replaced by hidden faster C loops in Numpy library. This principle is widely used for 3D operations, included colored pixel maps. The common example is a 3D plot.

**Common use: 3D plot**

[image]

```
x = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
```

(Borrowed from [this site](https://python.developpez.com/tutoriels/graphique-2d/matplotlib/#LIV-K))

`meshgrid` is used to create pairs of coordinates between -4 and +4 with .25 increments in each direction X and Y. Each pair is then used to find R, and Z from it. This way of preparing "a grid" of coordinates is frequently used in plotting 3D surfaces, or coloring 2D surfaces.

**Meshgrid under the hood**

The two arrays prepared by `meshgrid` are:

```
(array([[ 2,  7,  9, 20],
        [ 2,  7,  9, 20],
        [ 2,  7,  9, 20],
        [ 2,  7,  9, 20]]),

 array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7],
        [9, 9, 9, 9]]))
```

These arrays are created by repeating the values provided, either horizontally or vertically. The two arrays are shape compatible for a vector operation.

**Origin**

`numpy.meshgrid` comes [from MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), like many other [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) functions. So you can also study the examples from MATLAB to see `meshgrid` in use, the code for the 3D plotting looks [the same in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html).

Comment: I am new to this matlab/numpy way of vectorized computing. I came here because I wonder about the performance. In a lower-level programming language (like C) you would never waste time and memory to allocate and fill the `i` and `j` arrays just to read them again to prepare the result `c`. Any info on whether python is using strategies to optimize this away? Asked differently: Are the `i` and `j` arrays really occupying physical memory? Even more extreme: Is the expression `np.sqrt(i*i + j*j)` allocating two more additional temporary arrays, reading and writing the temporaries from/to RAM?

Comment: @fieres. I'm not a expert, but I know NumPy uses a clever array internal description to optimize operations, in particular to prevent useless duplication (look for 'array strides' and 'sparse matrix'). Common functions on array have been re-implemented into the array class (as `ufunc`) to take advantage of the many array optimizations. [Some info](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/).

Comment: I looked at the docs. As far as I understand, ufuncs do not optimize computations using lazy evaluation or result objects. So you need lots of memory. However, you have some means of optimizing memory usage manually by not using the pyton operators (`* / - +`) but using the explicit functions (`np.multiply` etc.) and passing the optional `out` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

meshgrid helps in creating a rectangular grid from two 1-D arrays of all pairs of points from the two arrays.

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now, if you have defined a function f(x,y) and you wanna apply this function to all the possible combination of points from the arrays 'x' and 'y', then you can do this:

```
f(*np.meshgrid(x, y))
```

Say, if your function just produces the product of two elements, then this is how a cartesian product can be achieved, efficiently for large arrays.

Referred from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90005/efficient-element-wise-function-computation-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

#### Basic Idea

Given possible x values, `xs`, (think of them as the tick-marks on the x-axis of a plot) and possible y values, `ys`, `meshgrid` generates the corresponding set of (x, y) grid points---analogous to `set((x, y) for x in xs for y in yx)`.  For example, if `xs=[1,2,3]` and `ys=[4,5,6]`, we'd get the set of coordinates `{(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (1,6), (2,6), (3,6)}`.

#### Form of the Return Value

However, the representation that [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid) returns is different from the above expression in two ways:

*First*, `meshgrid` lays out the grid points in a 2d array: rows correspond to different y-values, columns correspond to different x-values---as in `list(list((x, y) for x in xs) for y in ys)`, which would give the following array:

```
   [[(1,4), (2,4), (3,4)],
    [(1,5), (2,5), (3,5)],
    [(1,6), (2,6), (3,6)]]
```

*Second*, `meshgrid` returns the x and y coordinates separately (i.e. in two different numpy 2d arrays):

```
   xcoords, ycoords = (
       array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3]]),
       array([[4, 4, 4],
              [5, 5, 5],
              [6, 6, 6]]))
   # same thing using np.meshgrid:
   xcoords, ycoords = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
   # same thing without meshgrid:
   xcoords = np.array([xs] * len(ys)
   ycoords = np.array([ys] * len(xs)).T
```

Note, `np.meshgrid` can also generate grids for higher dimensions. Given xs, ys, and zs, you'd get back xcoords, ycoords, zcoords as 3d arrays. `meshgrid` also supports reverse ordering of the dimensions as well as sparse representation of the result.

#### Applications

Why would we want this form of output?

*Apply a function at every point on a grid:*
One motivation is that binary operators like (+, -, *, /, **) are overloaded for numpy arrays as elementwise operations.  This means that if I have a function `def f(x, y): return (x - y) ** 2` that works on two scalars, I can also apply it on two numpy arrays to get an array of elementwise results: e.g. `f(xcoords, ycoords)` or `f(*np.meshgrid(xs, ys))` gives the following on the above example:

```
array([[ 9,  4,  1],
       [16,  9,  4],
       [25, 16,  9]])
```

*Higher dimensional outer product:* I'm not sure how efficient this is, but you can get high-dimensional outer products this way: `np.prod(np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4]), axis=0)`.

*Contour plots in matplotlib:* I came across `meshgrid` when investigating [drawing contour plots with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) for [plotting decision boundaries](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_voting_decision_regions.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-voting-decision-regions-py). For this, you generate a grid with `meshgrid`, evaluate the function at each grid point (e.g. as shown above), and then pass the xcoords, ycoords, and computed f-values (i.e. zcoords) into the contourf function.

Comment: for some reason, the above expression for nd outer product in numpy results in shape (2, 3, 4) rather than (3, 2, 4).  This pytorch version gives the proper shape: `torch.stack(torch.meshgrid(*map(torch.tensor, [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3,4]]))).prod(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes:

```py
import numpy as np

def meshgrid(x , y):
    XX = []
    YY = []
    for colm in range(len(y)):
        XX.append([])
        YY.append([])
        for row in range(len(x)):
            XX[colm].append(x[row])
            YY[colm].append(y[colm])
    return np.asarray(XX), np.asarray(YY)
```

Lets take dataset of @Sarsaparilla's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404323/14919621) as example:

```py
y = [7, 6, 5]
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

xx, yy = meshgrid(x , y)
```

and it outputs:

```py
>>> xx
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

>>> yy
array([[7, 7, 7, 7],
       [6, 6, 6, 6],
       [5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To construct a direct product of arrays in NumPy, we can use the meshgrid function. It creates two-dimensional arrays that contain all possible combinations of elements from the two original arrays.

```
import numpy as np

# create two arrays
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])

# get direct product of arrays
product = np.array(np.meshgrid(arr1, arr2)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
print(product)
```

and then we receive:

```
[[1 4]
 [1 5]
 [1 6]
 [2 4]
 [2 5]
 [2 6]
 [3 4]
 [3 5]
 [3 6]]
```

Comment: Please explain what this adds to the answers already there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).