# Axes3D: Numpy arrays error while trying to build 3D plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, plot

Let's start from the beginning. This how I getting `x` and `y` values:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') # get current axis

w0 = np.arange(30, 80, 1) # x - values
w1 = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1) # y - values

X, Y = np.meshgrid(w0, w1) # no idea why to do that
```

Because I don't know how to avoid loops I go this way to calculate Z values:

```
    sizeWo = len(w0)
    sizeW1 = len(w1)
    Z = np.zeros((sizeWo, sizeW1))

    for i in xrange(0,sizeWo):
        for j in xrange(0,sizeW1):
            Z[i,j] = errorLose(w0[i], w1[j])

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z) # that lines generates the error (ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape)
```

Even this code generates the same error:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(w0, w1, Z) shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
plt.show()
```

What is wrong here and how to make it work?

`errorLose` function takes two values and calculates error using dataframe `data` behind:

```
def errorLose(w0,w1):
    return np.sum((data.Height - (w0 + w1 *data.Weight))**2)
```

This is how you can get the same data. This the link to the [csv file](http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/SOCR_Data_Dinov_020108_HeightsWeights):

```
data = pd.read_csv('weights_heights.csv', index_col='Index')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're very close. The issue is that you are creating `Z` to be `sizeWo x sizeW1` *but* `meshgrid` creates `X` and `Y` which are size `sizeW1 x sizeW0`. You can either setup `Z` differently:

```
Z = np.zeros((sizeW1, sizeWo))

for i in xrange(0,sizeWo):
    for j in xrange(0,sizeW1):
        Z[j,i] = errorLose(w0[i], w1[j])
```

Or you could keep `Z` the same and simply pass the transpose of `Z` to your plot constructor

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.transpose(Z))
```

**Update**

The reason that you need to use `meshgrid` is that your x and y coordinates are only *1D arrays* initially and `plot_surface` expects `X` and `Y` to be 2D arrays. What `meshgrid` does is it creates 2D arrays from the two inputs with every permutation of the two. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python/36014586#36014586) contains a more detailed discussion of `meshgrid`.

Comment: @Rocketq Sorry, that was a typo on my part. Updated now.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic)  But why do we need to `meshgrid`?

Comment: @Rocketq I added a little discussion on that at the end as well as a link to a potentially relevant answer