# Modify indexed object in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to update an `np.array` based on some indices.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([1,2])
a[b, :][:, b] += 1
```

Afterwards, `a` is unchanged, since just a copy got modified.
How can I modify the original object?

Comment: The problem is that `a[b,:]` is a copy.  The `[:,b]+=...` is modifying that copy, not the original `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an open mesh grid with [numpy.ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) and use it for the index. Using `ix_` takes advantage of broadcasting, it saves space because it doesn't need to create the *full complement* of indices.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ix_(b,b)
(array([[1],
       [2]]), array([[1, 2]]))
>>>
>>> a[np.ix_(b,b)] += 10
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 14, 15],
       [ 6, 17, 18]])
>>>
```

Using `ix_` is preferable for this use case but [numpy.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid) could also be used.  It has the disadvantage of creating a larger set of indices.

```
>>> np.meshgrid(b,b)
[array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]]), array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])]

>>> a[np.meshgrid(b,b)] *= -1
>>> a
array([[  0,   1,   2],
       [  3, -14, -15],
       [  6, -17, -18]])
>>>
```

Numpy's meshgrid is more typically used as descibed in [What is purpose of meshgrid in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36013063/2823755) and [Meshgrids and disambiguating rows and columns from Cartesian coordinates](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/meshgrids-and-disambiguating-rows-and-columns-from-cartesian-coordinates/)

Answer (score 0):

First select rows using array `b` and restrict the columns from position 1 to extract the square on the lower right corner.

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])   

# select the square on the lower right corner and increment it
>>> a[b, 1:] += 1
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  9, 10]])
```

Alternatively, you can also use this:

```
>>> a[b, b[0]:] += 1
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: This will increment the lower two rows, not the square to the lower right. Expected output is array([[ 1,  2,  3],[ 4,  6,  7],[ 7,  9, 10]])

Comment: This works for the particular ``b`` array in the question, but won't generalize to arbitrary ``b`` arrays. For this particular case, you could use ``b[1:,1:] += 1``, but I don't think that's what the question is asking.

Comment: @jakevdp I think you meant `a[1:, 1:] += 1` but that's equivalent to `a[b, 1:] += 1` ;)

Comment: You're right, I meant to say ``a[1:, 1:]``. My larger point is that solving a specific simplified example in a way that doesn't answer the more general question being asked is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the indexing in one step. For what you're trying to do, this will work:

```
a[b[:, np.newaxis], b] += 1
print(a)
# array([[ 1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  6,  7],
#        [ 7,  9, 10]])
```

When you index an array with multiple lists of indices, those lists are [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) together to index into the array. So if you have a 2x1 index and a 1x2 index, the resulting array slice is 2x2, and in this case references the 2x2 section of the array you were hoping to modify.