# reshaping 3 column numpy array

Tags: arrays, pandas, matplotlib, contourf

i have the following numpy array extracted from a dataframe that i want to reshape

## Extraction

```
x = c_df['x'].values
y = c_df['y'].values
z = c_df['z'].values
```

## convert to array

```
x_y_z = np.array([x, y, z])
x_y_z
```

## Array looks like this

```
array([[748260.27757, 748262.56478, 748263.52455, ..., 730354.86406,
        730374.75   , 730388.45066],
       [333346.25   , 333308.43521, 333296.25   , ..., 331466.13593,
        331453.84365, 331446.25   ],
       [  2840.     ,   2840.     ,   2840.     , ...,   2400.     ,
          2400.     ,   2400.     ]])
```

basically i want to reshape it to be able to plot using plt.contourf which required Z to be 2D array

so i assume the array needs to be reshaped to something like

```
 YYYYYYYYYY
Xzzzzzzzzzz
Xzzzzzzzzzz
Xzzzzzzzzzz
Xzzzzzzzzzz
```

is my assumption correct? if yes how to reshape the array.

Comment: Do you need [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691) ?

Comment: i tried, the df is so big i got this error, 
Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly [Numpy Mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy.mgrid) should be able to help you. However you might want some more explanation which can be found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python-numpy).

For the next time you can make it easier if you provide a simplified example of your problem.