# How can I permute only certain entries of numpy 2d-array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2d-array of shape (N, N) representing a NxN correlation matrix. This matrix is symmetric. Say N=5, then an example of this 2d-array would be:

```
x = np.array([[1.00, 0.46, 0.89, 0.76, 0.65],
              [0.46, 1.00, 0.83, 0.88, 0.29],
              [0.89, 0.83, 1.00, 0.57, 0.84],
              [0.76, 0.88, 0.57, 1.00, 0.39],
              [0.65, 0.29, 0.84, 0.39, 1.00]])
```

I would like to obtain P copies of `x` where the diagonal remains the same but the upper- and lower-triangular halves of the matrix are permuted in unison.

An example of one of these copies could be:

```
np.array([[1.00, 0.65, 0.89, 0.84, 0.39],
          [0.65, 1.00, 0.76, 0.83, 0.88],
          [0.89, 0.76, 1.00, 0.29, 0.57],
          [0.84, 0.83, 0.29, 1.00, 0.46],
          [0.39, 0.88, 0.57, 0.46, 1.00]])
```

It would be great if the solution doesn't take too long as the matrix I am using is of shape (100, 100) and I would like to obtain 10,000-100,000 copies.

My intuition would be to somehow obtain the lower or upper half of the matrix as a flattened array, do the permutation, and replace values in both upper and lower halves. This, however, would take me a while to figure out and would like to know if there is a more straight-forward approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1.00, 0.46, 0.89, 0.76, 0.65],
              [0.46, 1.00, 0.83, 0.88, 0.29],
              [0.89, 0.83, 1.00, 0.57, 0.84],
              [0.76, 0.88, 0.57, 1.00, 0.39],
              [0.65, 0.29, 0.84, 0.39, 1.00]])
j, i = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x.shape[0]), np.arange(x.shape[0]))
i, j = i.flatten(), j.flatten()
up_i, up_j = i[i < j], j[i< j]

elems = x[up_i, up_j]
np.random.shuffle(elems)
x[up_i, up_j] = elems
x[up_j, up_i] = elems
x
```

```
array([[1.  , 0.57, 0.88, 0.46, 0.76],
       [0.57, 1.  , 0.39, 0.29, 0.83],
       [0.88, 0.39, 1.  , 0.65, 0.89],
       [0.46, 0.29, 0.65, 1.  , 0.84],
       [0.76, 0.83, 0.89, 0.84, 1.  ]])
```

In case all your `x`s are of same shape, you need to call [meshgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python-numpy) and find indices corresponding to upper triangle only once.

This uses numpy fancy [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to fetch the non-diagonal elements.

Comment: This works great, thanks! Just to clarify, I only have one `x` and want many copies of random permutations.