# How to generate random points uniformly distributed over 40*40 rectangular region centered at (0,0) using python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to generate random points uniformly distributed over rectangular region centered at (0,0) using numpy and matplotlib.

Comment: meshgrid is made exactly for this purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python-numpy

Comment: `np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size=(1000, 2))` would generate 1000 random xy locations in the range `-20,20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohanC mentioned in comments, you need points with x and y coordinates between -20 and 20. To create them use:

```
np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size=(n,2))
```

with `n` being your desired number of points.
To plot them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(a[:,0],a[:,1])
```

sample plot for n=100 points:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The words, `random points uniformly distributed` is not easy to interprete. This is one of my interpretation shown as a runnable code. Sample output plot is also given.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create array of meshgrid over a rectangular region
# range of x: -cn/2, cn/2
# range of y: -rn/2, rn/2
cn, rn = 10, 14  # number of columns/rows
xs = np.linspace(-cn/2, cn/2, cn)
ys = np.linspace(-rn/2, rn/2, rn)

# meshgrid will give regular array-like located points
Xs, Ys = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)  #shape: rn x cn

# create some uncertainties to add as random effects to the meshgrid
mean = (0, 0)
varx, vary = 0.007, 0.008  # adjust these number to suit your need
cov = [[varx, 0], [0, vary]]
uncerts = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (rn, cn))

# plot the random-like meshgrid
plt.scatter(Xs+uncerts[:,:,0], Ys+uncerts[:,:,1], color='b');
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

You can change the values of `varx` and `vary` to change the level of randomness of the dot array on the plot.

[image: sample_plot]

**Edit**

One of the useful applications of such randomly scatter plots can be demonstrated by the following code and its output plot.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import markers

# create array of meshgrid over a rectangular region
# range of x: -cn/2, cn/2
# range of y: -rn/2, rn/2
cn, rn = 10, 14  # number of columns/rows
xs = np.linspace(-cn/2, cn/2, cn)
ys = np.linspace(-rn/2, rn/2, rn)

# meshgrid will give regular array-like located points
Xs, Ys = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)  #shape: rn x cn

# create some uncertainties to add as random effects to the meshgrid
mean = (0, 0)
varx, vary = 0.007, 0.008  # adjust these number to suit your need
cov = [[varx, 0], [0, vary]]
uncerts = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (rn, cn))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Create a list of polygon(s)
polygons = [Polygon([[-4,-6],[3,-5],[0,6]], closed=True), ]
p = PatchCollection(polygons, alpha=0.3)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

for ix, m in enumerate(xs):
    for iy, n in enumerate(ys):
        # If the point is inside the polygon,
        #  plot it as a red triangle
        if polygons[0].contains_point([m,n], 0):
            # locations are randomly moved away from grid
            ax.scatter(m+uncerts[iy,ix,0], n+uncerts[iy,ix,1], \
                       s=20, color='r', marker=markers.CARETUP);
        else:
            # plot simple dot
            # the locations are fixed regular grid
            ax.scatter(m, n, s=4)

plt.show()
```

[image: demo2]