# Countor plot is not displaying in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, contour

I'm trying to plot a contour map using plotly python,  but it's not working i getting a blank plot.

Here is my code,

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./temperature_2d.csv')
x = np.array(df.lon)
y = np.array(df.lat)
z = np.array(df.value).reshape(11, 87)
fig = go.Figure(data =
go.Contour(
    z=z,
    x=x, 
    y=y,
    colorscale = 'Hot',
    contours_coloring='heatmap'
))
fig.show()
```

Here is the data file that i used to plot [temperature_2d.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17q0yxh56PYqN5a4XnCe7TambutVloDQM/view?usp=sharing)

here is the output [image]

I'm completely new to things like ploting and all it will be really helpful if someone could explain what's wrong here and how to do this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly plotting i tried to grid your data first.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


df = pd.read_csv('./temperature_2d.csv')
x = np.array(df.lon)
y = np.array(df.lat)
z = np.array(df.value)


xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
Z = griddata((x,y),z,(X,Y), method='cubic')



fig = go.Figure(data =
go.Contour(
z=Z,
x=xi,
y=yi,
colorscale = 'Hot',
contours_coloring='heatmap'
))
fig.show()
```

[image: Example Figure]

Comment: Thanks that's awesome, can you explain why did my code didn't work.I'm newbie to data visualization so i do not know what exactly my code did there. thank you for your time it was really helpful :)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at these links:              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-python-numpy                           https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html  https://plotly.com/python/reference/contour/