# How to produce a 3D plot of a 2D numpy matrix in python/matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I have a 2D numpy matrix that I would like to plot as a 3D surface plot using matplotlib.

For each X between X0 and Xend and Y between Y0 and Yend, I would like to plot a dot with a Z-value equal to matrix[X,Y].

I suppose that I could manually unroll the matrix and produce an array of X values, an array of Y values, and a 1D array of Z values, but this seems awkward and inefficient.

I tried

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plt.matshow(bias_array)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(range(X0,Xend), range(Y0,Yend), bias_array[X0:Xend,Y0:Yend], marker='o')
```

but this produces

shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (5,) and arg 2 with shape (25,).

(note that both the X and Y ranges are 5 for this example case)

because matplotlib does not know to go into the matrix and pick out X,Y for each data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `np.meshgrid` function.

[numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013063/what-is-the-purpose-of-meshgrid-in-numpy)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

# Dummy data
X0, Xend = 0, 5
Y0, Yend = 0, 5
bias_array = np.random.rand(10, 10)

# This creates 2D coordinate arrays for X and Y
X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(X0, Xend), range(Y0, Yend))

Z = bias_array[X0:Xend, Y0:Yend]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, this is the perfect answer!